# Need help reading multiple rows of rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

So I have to read in all restaurant records in a MSSQL database and each resaurant has a list of tables. My issue goes as I know how to read one restaurant row:

```cs
public Restaurant GeefRestaurant(int id)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
            string naam;
            string email;
            string telefoonnummer;
            int postcode;
            string gemeente;
            string straat;
            string huisnummer;
            Keuken keuken;
            int tafelnummerOld = -1;
            int tafelnummer = 0;
            int aantalPlaatsen = 0;
            bool isBezet = false;
            bool first = true;
            Locatie l = null;
            Restaurant r = null;
            List<Tafel> tafels = new();
            cmd.CommandText = $"select r.Id RestaurantId, r.naam, r.email, r.telefoonnummer, r.keuken, l.id locatieid, l.postcode, l.gemeente, l.straat, l.huisnummer, t.Tafelnummer, t.aantalplaatsen, t.isbezet " +
                $"from Restaurant r " +
                $"left join locatie l on r.locatieid = l.id " +
                $"left join tafel t on r.id = t.restaurantid " +
                $"where r.id = {id}";
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (r == null)
                {
                    postcode = (int)reader["Postcode"];
                    gemeente = (string)reader["Gemeente"];
                    straat = reader["Straat"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Straat"];
                    huisnummer = reader["Huisnummer"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Huisnummer"];
                    keuken = (Enum.Parse<Keuken>((string)reader["keuken"]));
                    naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                    email = (string)reader["Email"];
                    telefoonnummer = (string)reader["telefoonnummer"];

                    l = new(postcode, gemeente, straat, huisnummer);
                    l.ZetId((int)reader["LocatieId"]);

                    r = new(naam, l, telefoonnummer, email, keuken);
                    r.ZetId((int)reader["RestaurantId"]);
                }

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Tafelnummer"))) // heeft tafels
                {
                    tafelnummer = (int)reader["Tafelnummer"];
                    if (tafelnummer != tafelnummerOld)
                    {
                        // Nieuwe tafel of de eerste
                        if (tafelnummerOld > 0)
                        {
                            // Maak tafel, einde bereikt
                            Tafel t = new(tafelnummerOld, aantalPlaatsen, isBezet);
                            r.VoegTafelToe(t);
                        }
                        first = true;
                        tafelnummerOld = tafelnummer;
                    }
                    if (first)
                    {
                        aantalPlaatsen = (int)reader["AantalPlaatsen"];
                        isBezet = (bool)reader["IsBezet"];
                        first = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            if (tafelnummer > 0)
            {
                Tafel t = new(tafelnummer, aantalPlaatsen, isBezet);
                r.VoegTafelToe(t);
            }
            return r;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RestaurantRepositoryException("GebruikerRegistreren - repo", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't exactly know how to read all of them out in code, I know the sql command, I've tried numerous things but none of them did what it was supposed to do :/. What I want is to start reading a Restaurant row, read out all of it's tables and then move on to the next until all data is read.

I tried something like this but this doesn't work...

```cs
public IReadOnlyList<Restaurant> GeefAlleRestaurants()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
            string naam;
            string email;
            string telefoonnummer;
            int postcode;
            string gemeente;
            string straat;
            string huisnummer;
            Keuken keuken;
            int restaurantIdOld = -1;
            int restaurantId = 0;
            int tafelnummerOld = -1;
            int tafelnummer = 0;
            int aantalPlaatsen = 0;
            bool isBezet = false;
            bool first = true;
            bool firstRestaurant = true;
            Locatie l = null;
            List<Restaurant> restaurants = new();
            //Restaurant r = null;
            List<Tafel> tafels = new();
            cmd.CommandText = $"select r.Id RestaurantId, r.naam, r.email, r.telefoonnummer, r.keuken, l.id locatieid, l.postcode, l.gemeente, l.straat, l.huisnummer, t.Tafelnummer, t.aantalplaatsen, t.isbezet " +
                $"from Restaurant r " +
                $"left join locatie l on r.locatieid = l.id " +
                $"left join tafel t on r.id = t.restaurantid";
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //TODO!
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("RestaurantId"))) // heeft restaurants
                {
                    restaurantId = (int)reader["RestaurantId"];
                    if (restaurantId != restaurantIdOld)
                    {
                        // Nieuwe restaurant of het eerste
                        if (restaurantIdOld > 0)
                        {
                            // Maak restaurant, einde bereikt
                            postcode = (int)reader["Postcode"];
                            gemeente = (string)reader["Gemeente"];
                            straat = reader["Straat"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Straat"];
                            huisnummer = reader["Huisnummer"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Huisnummer"];
                            keuken = (Enum.Parse<Keuken>((string)reader["keuken"]));
                            naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                            email = (string)reader["Email"];
                            telefoonnummer = (string)reader["telefoonnummer"];
                            r = new(naam, l, telefoonnummer, email, keuken);
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Tafelnummer")))
                                {
                                    tafelnummer = (int)reader["Tafelnummer"];
                                    if (tafelnummer != tafelnummerOld)
                                    {
                                        if (tafelnummerOld > 0)
                                        {
                                            Tafel t = new(tafelnummer, aantalPlaatsen, isBezet);
                                            r.VoegTafelToe(t);
                                        }
                                        tafelnummerOld = tafelnummer;
                                        aantalPlaatsen = (int)reader["aantalplaatsen"];
                                        isBezet = (bool)reader["isbezet"];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            restaurants.Add(r);
                        }
                        firstRestaurant = true;
                        restaurantIdOld = restaurantId;
                        if (firstRestaurant)
                        {
                            naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                            email = (string)reader["Email"];
                            telefoonnummer = (string)reader["telefoonnummer"];
                            postcode = (int)reader["Postcode"];
                            gemeente = (string)reader["Gemeente"];
                            straat = reader["Straat"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Straat"];
                            huisnummer = reader["Huisnummer"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Huisnummer"];
                            keuken = (Enum.Parse<Keuken>((string)reader["keuken"]));

                            l = new(postcode, gemeente, straat, huisnummer);
                            l.ZetId((int)reader["LocatieId"]);

                            r = new(naam, l, telefoonnummer, email, keuken);
                            r.ZetId((int)reader["RestaurantId"]);
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Tafelnummer")))
                                {
                                    tafelnummer = (int)reader["Tafelnummer"];
                                    if (tafelnummer != tafelnummerOld)
                                    {
                                        if (tafelnummerOld > 0)
                                        {
                                            Tafel t = new(tafelnummer, aantalPlaatsen, isBezet);
                                            r.VoegTafelToe(t);
                                        }
                                        tafelnummerOld = tafelnummer;
                                        aantalPlaatsen = (int)reader["aantalplaatsen"];
                                        isBezet = (bool)reader["isbezet"];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            restaurants.Add(r);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            return restaurants;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RestaurantRepositoryException("GebruikerRegistreren - repo", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to make another methods that returns a list so I could use this method instead of trying to get all the Tafel records from the db but I get an error that the connection was already opened and I don't know if that is good practice...

Comment: I would point you to reading about ORM and use those libraries in your context. There is one very good without a lot of baggage called [Dapper](https://dapperlib.github.io/Dapper/). However this will require a bit of effort on your side because there are some things to learn there albeit it will repay you on the long run

Comment: Careful, that query looks like it's wide open to injection attacks; a serious a fatal security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL query is not guaranteed to return the records in any particular order if you don't specify one explicitly. Since you want to add a new restaurant to the list whenever the restaurant id changes, you must order by the restaurant id

```sql
SELECT r.Id RestaurantId, r.naam, r.email, ...
FROM Restaurant r
LEFT JOIN locatie l ON r.locatieid = l.id
LEFT JOIN tafel t ON r.id = t.restaurantid
ORDER BY r.id
```

Note that because the restaurant id is the primary key, it cannot be null. Therefore, don't test it for DbNull. But location and tables are left-joined and can therefore be null, e.g. if a restaurant doesn't have a location or tables defined.

Tables should occur only once per restaurant, so `(restaurantid, Tafelnummer)` must be a compound primary key or have a unique index. You could also have a separate `tafelid` primary key being unique for the whole tafels table.

Locations can occur in any order and can be assigned to several restaurants. Therefore, I suggest adding them to a dictionary with the table number as key. This enables us to look then up easily.

The logic then becomes

```cs
List<Restaurant> restaurants = new();
Dictionary<int, Locatie> locations = new();
int restaurantIdOld = -1;
... (skipping details)
while (reader.Read()) {
    int restaurantId = (int)reader["RestaurantId"];
    if (restaurantId != restaurantIdOld) {
        Locatie l = null;
        if (reader["LocatieId"] is int locId &&
           !locations.TryGetValue(locId, out l))
        {
            //TODO: get location fields
            l = new(locId, postcode, gemeente, straat, huisnummer);
            locations.Add(locId, l);
        }

        //TODO: get restaurant fields
        r = new(restaurantId, naam, l, telefoonnummer, email, keuken);
        restaurants.Add(r);
    }
    if (reader["Tafelnummer"] is int tafelnummer) {
        //TODO: get table fields
        // No need to test whether this is a new table. Tables are unique.
        Tafel t = new(restaurantId, tafelnummer, aantalPlaatsen, isBezet);
        r.VoegTafelToe(t);
    }
}
return restaurants;
```

We can also remove the $ from the SQL string since we don't have any string interpolation.

There is no need to declare all the variables in advance. Declare them in the scope they are needed.

I skipped some details. Use a [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration) for the reader. This will close it automatically at the end of the scope.

```cs
using SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You can do the same with commands and connections.

Comment: I tested this and it worked, I've never worked with composite primary keys either but I had thought about an issue with table numbers and restaurants. This solution is so much shorter than everything I have tried so far... I guess I just try too hard at times... Thanks!